# I followed the tutorial on webapp2 for creating a hello world app in detail, but it doesn't work

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

I have created a folder.

In that folder,

I have created

> app.yaml

It contains:

```
application: helloworld
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: helloworld.py
```

I have created

> helloworld.py

It contains:

```
print 'Content-Type: text/plain'
print ''
print 'Hello, world!'
```

When I click on browse in the Google App Engine launcher, this application should run and display

> Hello, world!

according to the tutorial.

But when I click on browse, the browser displays an empty web page.

If I click on developer tools in Chrome, I can see that the generated web site is:

```
<html>
<head><style type="text/css"></style></head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

What might be wrong? Why is this simple hello world example not working for me?

EDIT:

Here is a link to the tutorial in question:
https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/tutorials/gettingstarted/helloworld.html#tutorials-gettingstarted-helloworld

Comment: Not sure what is the purpose of starting that tutorial with showing you the really old & not recommended way of doing things but you can safely skip that step and go to down to the "**Next...**" section on the bottom of the page and click on the "[Continue to Using the webapp2 Framework](https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/tutorials/gettingstarted/usingwebapp2.html#tutorials-gettingstarted-usingwebapp2)." which starts showing you the better way to handle requests. Or you could also use the link suggested in the answer below.

Comment: That's not an official tutorial, and it looks wrong. Use a tutorial from Google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what tutorial you are using, but that CGI style doesn't work with the python27 runtime (and the older one hasn't been available for years). You should use the [actual GAE tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/helloworld).